# Swift MessageKit - Argument labels '(type:)' do not match any available overloads

Tags: swift, xcode, messagekit

I have begun to try to use `MessageKit` from the Firebase Chat tutorial that uses `MessageKit` so far. I have come across this error that does not appear inside the tutorial project. When I try to use the code from the tutorial project I am getting this error and am not sure how to solve it.

**Argument labels '(type:)' do not match any available overloads**

```
let cameraItem = UIBarButtonItem(type: .system)
```

Comment: Please ⌃⌘-click on the symbol to see the header file where the `init` methods are declared or retype *UIBarButtonItem(* and use code completion. It also could be a custom extension providing this `init` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot create an **[UIBarButtonItem](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibarbuttonitem)** like that because it's not part of the documentation. Here is the official documentation of [UIBarButtonItem](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibarbuttonitem) with different initialisers.

If you want to create a [UIBarButtonItem](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibarbuttonitem) with default system items:

```
UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .cancel, target: self, action: Selector("handleCancel")
```

Here is a list of all [UIBarButtonItem.SystemItem](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibarbuttonitem/systemitem) that you can use to create a  [UIBarButtonItem](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibarbuttonitem)

You can also create a **UIBarButtonItem** with different data, like images, text etc... Take a look at this [page](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibarbuttonitem)